# Expression builder cannot select

Tags: qgis

In the latest version of Qgis (2.12.3) when trying to create a filter the feature of right clicking and selecting a value does not work. What am I missing ?

I have attached a picture :
[image]

At this stage I want to right click and make a selection. However nothing happens. The data refers to a joined table and the attribute table does show values.